# VBScript to remove duplicate numbers from subtitle file by re-numbering

Tags: regex, replace, vbscript, pattern-matching, subtitle

I have a subtitle(.srt) file looking like below:

```
2
00:04:22,504 --> 00:04:23,520
Hello?

3
00:04:27,860 --> 00:04:29,112
Hey wait!
Hello!

3
00:06:18,860 --> 00:06:21,112
Uhh!

3
00:06:29,860 --> 00:06:32,112
Ah!

4
00:07:19,232 --> 00:07:21,284
What are you doing here?

5
00:07:21,608 --> 00:07:22,708
Tell me!

...
```

As you can see the number `3` is repeated thrice in that file, which I want to replace by re-numbering the entire subtitle file(as I guess that is the only option, because this duplication is at multiple places in this file).

I have created below script for selecting that file and am trying to replace the duplicated numbers with fresh new generated numbers(iteration numbers), but it doesn't work.

```
Dim strFile, objFS

strFile = SelectFile( )
If strFile = "" Then
    WScript.Echo "No file selected."
End If


Function SelectFile( )
    Dim objExec, strMSHTA, wshShell

    SelectFile = ""

    strMSHTA = "mshta.exe ""about:" & "<" & "input type=file id=FILE>" _
             & "<" & "script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject')" _
             & ".GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);" & "<" & "/script>"""

    Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
    Set objExec = wshShell.Exec( strMSHTA )

    SelectFile = objExec.StdOut.ReadLine( )

    Set objExec = Nothing
    Set wshShell = Nothing
End Function

Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Set objFile2 = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile, 8, True)
x = 0
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine = objFile.ReadLine
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.Pattern = "^\d+$"
    Set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strLine)
    If colMatches.Count > 0 Then
        x = x + 1
        strLine = x
        strNewLine = Replace(strLine,strLine,x)
        objFile2.WriteLine strLine
    End If
Loop
```

Can anyone help, figuring out, how to make this work ?

Comment: can it be done using other technologies than vbscript?

Comment: As I have already created VBScript so far, I would prefer vbscript based answer, but if you have working solution then please add your answer or put a url to your script in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In VBScript use a [regular expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2.aspx) with a [replacement function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4) and a global counter:

```
f = "C:\path\to\your.srt"
n = 1  'global counter

Function Renumber(m, g1, g2, pos, src)
  Renumber = g1 & n & g2
  n = n + 1  'increment global counter after current value was used
End Function

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "(^|\r\n\r\n)\d+(\r\n)"
re.Global = True

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = fso.OpenTextFile(f).ReadAll
txt = re.Replace(txt, GetRef("Renumber"))
fso.OpenTextFile(f, 2).Write txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `Unix` box, or a `Unix` VM, or if you can emulate an Unix environment with `awk` it can be done in one line:

**Command:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=1} $0~/^[0-9]+$/ {print c++} $0~/[a-zA-Z,:\-!?]|^$/{print}' input_sub.txt > output_sub.txt
```

**Tested on:**

```
2
00:04:22,504 --> 00:04:23,520
Hello?

3
00:04:27,860 --> 00:04:29,112
Hey wait!
Hello!

3
00:06:18,860 --> 00:06:21,112
Uhh!

3
00:06:29,860 --> 00:06:32,112
Ah!

4
00:07:19,232 --> 00:07:21,284
What are you doing here?

5
00:07:21,608 --> 00:07:22,708
Tell me!
```

**Output:**

```
1
00:04:22,504 --> 00:04:23,520
Hello?

2
00:04:27,860 --> 00:04:29,112
Hey wait!
Hello!

3
00:06:18,860 --> 00:06:21,112
Uhh!

4
00:06:29,860 --> 00:06:32,112
Ah!

5
00:07:19,232 --> 00:07:21,284
What are you doing here?

6
00:07:21,608 --> 00:07:22,708
Tell me!
```